# How to initialize an EntityManager with the help of Springs (without using persistent.xml file)?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to initialize an Entity Manager with the help of Springs (without using persistent.xml file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Spring bean `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and set the `packagesToScan` property to point to package containing your entities.
Note in addition to Java configuration provided by Kartoch above, you can configure this bean in your spring context xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Using annotations `@Configuration`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "fr.plil.sio.jpa")
@EnableJpaRepositories("fr.plil.sio.jpa")
public class JpaAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:jpa_example;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSource.setUsername("foo");
        dataSource.setPassword("bar");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("fr.plil.sio.jpa");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```